# Generation of Dynamic Dropdown based on number of rows in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a dynamic drop down menu. For example, if i have 3 rows, I want the drop down values are 1 , 2 , 3 and so on.

I have tried the code below, it works shows dynamic list but there is a '0' in the list I can't understand why

In my controller (this will get the S_Rank column which is exactly what i need to list in my drop down menu)

```
$ranks = array();
foreach($applications as $application) {
$ranks[] = $application->S_Rank;}
```

this is my view

```
{{Form::select('Abstract_Status_ID' ,[$ranks], $application->S_ID, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' =>$application->S_Rank] )}}
```

the result where it shows the weird '0'

http://prntscr.com/nlwihy

Comment: So is S_Rank a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put the `$ranks` array into another array.

```
{{ Form::select('Abstract_Status_ID', $ranks, $application->S_ID, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => $application->S_Rank]) }}
```